# Saxon: Need to restart Glassfish after every redeployment

Tags: java, xml, xslt, glassfish

I have a web application which uses Java `javax.xml.transform.Template`'s to cache static XSLT's and I'm using the Saxon HE processor to transform XML's using those templates.

My problem is that every time I redeploy my application on Glassfish, I get this exception while doing the transform:

```
[2014-07-24T11:14:19.579+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1406193259579] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  This web container has not yet been started
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2819)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1288)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1272)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1506)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel.getDocumentBuilder(DOMObjectModel.java:208)
    at net.sf.saxon.lib.SerializerFactory.getReceiver(SerializerFactory.java:251)
    at net.sf.saxon.lib.SerializerFactory.getReceiver(SerializerFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.openResult(Controller.java:2290)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2043)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1903)
    ... my own packages start here
```

The only thing I can do is just restart Glassfish (which has a couple more applications on it so takes a while) and try again. It's really annoying and hampering my development cycle.

Any thoughts?

**PROBLEM AND WORKAROUND FOUND**

The problem was with having the Saxon lib in Glassfish' endorsed directory. I tried to be smart and just let Saxon handle the javax XSLT stuff for all applications instead of whatever default transformer was installed. Packing the Saxon lib with my app resolved the issue.

Comment: Something in that stack is not cleaning up properly on undeploy?

Comment: Yeah, that's my feeling, but it's quite hard to pinpoint what exactly.

Comment: [This](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/glassfish-3-exceptions-happens-on-war-redeployment/) might be a lead.